# How can I integrate bill and invoice in seperate tables or into one single payment table or two?

Tags: sql, linq, database-design, rdbms

I have a bills table. bill provided by the vendor

I have a invoice table. bill provided to the customer

How can i link it with payment? .Bill will be the record of the payment made to vendor whereas invoice will be the payment received from the customer.

```
option1 : Create one payment table with billid and invoice id
option2 : create two payment table paymentinvoicedetails and paymentbillsdetails with paymentmaster
```

What could be the better option or there can be a third option? The reason i am asking it because more or less there fields are almost same with two or three fields different

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely based on your business requirements.

If both Vendor Payment and Customer Receipts are different properties/column or different child tables, or tax/discount related tables then my suggestion is, create separate table for each payment (`paymentinvoicedetails ,paymentbillsdetails` ). Then you can properly manage the Foreign Key relation to both the table as well as other related Master/Child tables also.

But, if the properties almost same and there is no different Foreign Key masters, then you can create a single payment table with relation to both `bill (billid)` and `invoice (invoiceid)` tables and a column `payment_type` (not mandatory, you can simply identify the payment mode by considering the `billid/invoiceid` is NULL) to mark the record as whether it is Vendor Payment/Customer Receipt.

Answer (score 0):

Creating one payment table with bill-id, invoice-id, the amount payed and a transaction type is enough.

Comment: You can not generelize your answer like this. You don't know enough of the business scenario.

Comment: Yes I am assuming that this is a simple business scenario, since on the question he wrote that he has only a bills table and an a invoice table, (that’s it). If the scenario is much complicated, then I agree, but then we need more info on this. On my answer, Im triying to help the user on how he can proceed. In my opinion this should be enough to get the job done :)

Comment: how do you know it will get his job done? It is _a_ solution, but you can't know if it's the _right_ solution.

Comment: Maztt is asking what is better A, B or is there a possible C. Both are possible solutions. I propose A. If you think B is better then that’s ok. If you know about a better way then let him know, maybe it helps.

For a simple business scenario, A is enough, no need for B (Unless the business scenario is much complicated.)

Comment: I don't think anything is better. I don't know what is better. Your answer _may_ help, but it's just a guess. It's like choosing a religion. You could be right, but at the end it's a guess.